# Does aggregate CRS imply firm-level CRS?

Tags: general-equilibrium, producer-theory, aggregate-production, input-output

Suppose that a production set $Y \subset \mathbb R^I$ has the following two properties:

1. Constant returns to scale: $\forall y \in Y, \alpha \geq 0$, we have $\alpha y \in Y$.
2. Separability: For some $\widetilde I \subset I$, there exist sets $Y^i \subset \mathbb R^I$ for all $i \in \widetilde I$ such that (a) for all $y^i \in Y^i$, $y^i_{j \neq i} \leq 0$ and (b) $Y = \{ \sum_{i \in \widetilde I} y^i | \forall i\in \widetilde I,  y^i \in Y^i \}$.

Does this imply that one may take the sets $Y^i$ to be constant returns to scale? Formally, do there exist sets $\widetilde Y^i \subset \mathbb R^I$ for all $i \in \widetilde I$ such that

- for all $y^i \in \widetilde Y^i$, $y^i_{j \neq i} \leq 0$,
- $Y = \{ \sum_{i \in \widetilde I} y^i | \forall i\in \widetilde I,  y^i \in \widetilde Y^i \}$, and
- for all $y^i \in \widetilde Y^i$ and $\alpha \geq 0$, we have $\alpha y^i \in \widetilde Y^i$?

Comment: With unit elasticity firms and free entry, can't you get each firm having no meaningful returns to scale (they only operate at a single quantity or 0) but aggregate constant returns to scale? My thinking is that when you double the quantity of labor and capital you double the amount of firms and therefore double the output, but each firm does the same old thing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't think this works within the formalism described above, though. If what you had in mind is that each firm is its own $i$, then the profile where you e.g. produce double of one firm's quantity is not in $Y$, the aggregate production set. If what you had in mind is that all firms that produce the same type of good should be thought of as producing the same $i$, then that would mean $Y^i$ actually is CRS.